# Why do some feed entries not post in chat?

Tags: support, chat, feed

I have created a few feeds for Chat containing entries of interest to the [Rebol and Red](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) community. One such feed that I've recently been testing contains [recent tweets by the respective creators of Rebol and Red](http://rebol.info/feeds/twitter.feed) and another that tracks recent [announcements from a public area within a community darknet](http://rebol.info/feeds/announce.feed) (don't ask, there *are* reasons). However, I've noticed that the Feeds bot is prone to skipping entries and it's difficult to discern why.

I've been careful to ensure that:

- The feeds are valid Atom feeds,
- Are served with the correct MIME-type,
- Feeds contain an accurate Updated field,
- Entries contain unique IDs,
- Entries contain Title, Content and Author fields,
- Entries have correct Published and Updated fields,
- Entry links are unique (even when they are not, I'll add a unique query string that they are).

For most of these requirements, knowledge on what the Feeds bot likes has been hard-won with many feeds previously added direct from source not working at all and having to be refitted for purpose. However, with my latest feeds meeting the above criteria, I'm at a loss as to why they're not posting when:

- Earlier entries from the feed have posted (i.e. the Feed *has* worked),
- Newer entries from other feeds have posted (i.e. the Feeds bot *is* working),
- feedvalidator.org continues to report each feed as valid.

Is there any way to find out why either the feed or entries are being rejected (if indeed that's what is happening), or at least a minimum requirement for feeds/entries to be accepted by the Feeds bot?