# Missing item in chat RSS feed

Tags: bug, chat, feed

A bounty was set on [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53094/building-static-hash-table-with-particular-collisions) on 2016-02-21 17:40:10. The bounty appears in the [RSS feed](https://cs.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured). We have a [chat feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2710/computer-science?tab=feeds) that posts items from that feed, but [it's missing this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-349?tab=recent) ([transcript for that day](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2710/2016/2/21)). Subsequent items in that feed have been posted. Why is that one item missing?

Comment: See also this missed question https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50135097#50135097 and the prove that it was in the feed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Rxw.png

Comment: Related: [Why do some feed entries not post in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222712/255554)