# The chat feed reader doesn't post an entry present in an RSS feed

Tags: bug, chat, feed

I bountied in 2019 these questions: a support request and a bug

- [Why do some feed entries not post in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222712/why-do-some-feed-entries-not-post-in-chat)
- [Missing item in chat RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276198/missing-item-in-chat-rss-feed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and nothing happened. I guess 2019 was a bad year ...

Today it was again [brought to my attention](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58545779#58545779) that the SE Chat RSS feed reader skips a beat now and then. This time the [HNQ History room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58527649#58527649) missed a question. That feed comes from my [HNQ App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314073/158100) and that specific question from History.se is available in the feed:

[image: feed history]

When I setup that [same feed in a new room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58546090#58546090) I do get a post which makes me believe/conclude the app is working correctly. I checked the logging and I see requests for the history feed in the log:

[image: HNQ app log]

Here is my request:

I know Chat is not the Cash Cow of Stack Exchange. I know only so few devs dare to touch it. I accept it is unlikely to see a fix for this in 6 to 8 weeks. But ...

Can you please post an answer that *explains* the behavior we observe, the cause(s) that lead to these mishaps and if there is anything I can do on my end to prevent it from happening?

Yes, I know that triaging a bug also takes time and I'm sure this one might not be easy. Still, it takes less time than to actually fix it. Having an answer here gives the users that depend on the Chat RSS feeds the reassurance the setup is not the problem. That is time-efficient for them. And for me.

If you need assistance, for example by providing a stable test feed from my app, let me know. I'm happy to help.

Let's give this a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)